# Why my alpha version on google actions doesn't connect my actions from dialogflow?

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-developers-console

I have a project on Dialogflow where I have intents, firebase where I'm using functions, and google actions console where I want to put my app.

package.json

[image: package.json]

I create intents in my nodejs and actions-on-google in VSC and deploy it with `firebase deploy --only functions`. I have an HTTPS API webhook from functions in firebase and I put it into Dialogflow Fulfillment.

[image]

[image]

If I change something in Dialogflow I used integrations to integrate Dialogflow intents with Google Assistant. My main problem is where I try to deploy to an alpha version on google actions console I don't see anything in the Actions label only 3 commas. I tried to use webhook from firebase to connect it with the google action console but It doesn't work.

Webhook on google actions console

[image]

Alpha

[image]

Intergrations on DialogFlow

[image]

Develop tab

[image]

Comment: There are several things confusing about the screen shots you've provided. Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Integration tab in Dialogflow and a larger image from the Actions Console where it looks like you've specified the webhook. Can you also include a screen shot of the Actions Console where you've selected "Develop" on the top menu and "Actions" on the left menu?

Comment: I added screens shots. If you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: If I removed my global intents on google actions and deploy the new alpha version these commas disappear and Action label is empty..